# Testing with test user doesn't work

Tags: android, testing, billing

I'm trying to test my app with "android.test.purchased" reserved item and a test user i created.

My application's is signed and uploaded but the application is not public.

When my test user tries to purchase the item with the reserved item "android.test.purchased", the signature verification fails. It works on my device (with the developer account on it).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test account was not a gmail.com address.

I changed it and it works.